# How to add event listener for html element inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

For some reasons, I have to add an event listener for an html element inside `useEffect` hook. And the element is from a component named `Comp`. So I wrote this:

```js
const Comp = () => {
  return (
    <div className="ele"></div>
    // something else
  )
}

const App = () => { 
  useEffect(() => {
    const ele = document.querySelector(`.ele`)
    const handleClick = () => {}
    ele.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
    return () => ele.removeEventListener('click', handleClick)
  }, [])
  return  <Comp/> 
}
```

I can't add event listener for `ele` inside `Comp` directly since `Comp` is a third library component. So the only way is to query `ele` and then add event listener in `useEffect`.

But this code didn't work. When using `window.getEventListener(ele)` in devtools, it returned a null object without `click` property. Also, the `click` event didn't work. And I found the code below can work:

```js
const App => { 
  const divRef = useRef(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClick = () => {}
    const ele = divRef.current.querySelector(`.ele`)
    ele.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
    return () => ele.removeEventListener('click', handleClick)
  }, [])
  return (
     <div ref={divRef}> <Comp/></div>
  )
}
```

So what is the corret way to solve this problem? Why the first way failed while the second way succeeded ?

Comment: <div className="ele" onClick={handleClick}></div>

Comment: @ShahVipul I can't access the doms of `Comp` since it is a third library component. I can only use it.

Comment: Even if it's a third-party component, still it's a component in react .So you can add onClick. The only issue you might face is component isn't accepting onClick props so in that scenario you need to add onClick in a third-party component.

Comment: @ShahVipul I get it. You mean I can write like `<Comp onClick={}>`, right?

Comment: yes, you can add this way.

Answer (score 2):

Using exactly the code you shared (the first snippet) it works perfectly fine, the listener is initiated.
Instead of testing your code by using `window.getEventListener(ele)` just add some placeholder `console.log` and try again.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The issue is because there are multiple `Comp` components in the page. So I need to use `querySelectorAll` to get all `ele`s instead of just using `querySelector` to get the first `ele`.